# SQL Server Switch Based on grouping of previous values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of order information in the following format:

```
╔══════════════╦══════╦════════════════╦═══════════╦═════════╦══════════╗
║ Order Number ║ Line ║      Item      ║ Warehouse ║ Carrier ║ Quantity ║
╠══════════════╬══════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬══════════╣
║          255 ║    1 ║ STUFFED-ANIMAL ║ WH1       ║ UPS     ║        3 ║
║          256 ║    1 ║ BLOCKS         ║ WH2       ║ FEDEX   ║        1 ║
║          257 ║    1 ║ DOLL           ║ WH1       ║ UPS     ║        1 ║
║          257 ║    2 ║ DRESS          ║ WH1       ║ UPS     ║        3 ║
║          257 ║    3 ║ SHOES          ║ WH2       ║ UPS     ║        1 ║
║          258 ║    1 ║ CHAIR          ║ WH3       ║ FEDEX   ║        1 ║
║          258 ║    2 ║ CHAIR          ║ WH3       ║ UPS     ║        2 ║
╚══════════════╩══════╩════════════════╩═══════════╩═════════╩══════════╝
```

I am trying to query it in such a way that I partition it into groups based on a unique combination of columns.

In my example, I would like the following result:

```
╔════════════════╦══════╦════════════════╦═══════════╦═════════╦══════════╗
║ Package-Number ║ Line ║      Item      ║ Warehouse ║ Carrier ║ Quantity ║
╠════════════════╬══════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬═════════╬══════════╣
║ 255            ║    1 ║ STUFFED-ANIMAL ║ WH1       ║ UPS     ║        3 ║
║ 256            ║    1 ║ BLOCKS         ║ WH2       ║ FEDEX   ║        1 ║
║ 257-1          ║    1 ║ DOLL           ║ WH1       ║ UPS     ║        1 ║
║ 257-1          ║    2 ║ DRESS          ║ WH1       ║ UPS     ║        3 ║
║ 257-2          ║    3 ║ SHOES          ║ WH2       ║ UPS     ║        1 ║
║ 258-1          ║    1 ║ CHAIR          ║ WH3       ║ FEDEX   ║        1 ║
║ 258-2          ║    2 ║ CHAIR          ║ WH3       ║ UPS     ║        2 ║
╚════════════════╩══════╩════════════════╩═══════════╩═════════╩══════════╝
```

To break it down I would like to do the following:

If the order number, warehouse, and carrier are the same that is one 'partition.' If there is only one partition then we just leave the order number as the package number, otherwise we break it down into packages. These packages are numbered by the same set of values being the same, but now have a number denoting which package it is.

I was looking into using `row_number() over (partition by...` that I found after searching for similar issues but I don't think it is exactly what I'm looking for.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: 257-1 and 257-1 again?

Comment: Sounds to me like ROW_NUMBER is exactly what you need.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Since they share the same order number, warehouse, and carrier they should be the same package number.

Comment: @user2827048: both records related to order number `258` have the same line number (`1`), can you confirm that it is a typo?

Comment: @GMB yes that was a typo, I'll change it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky.  Having `count(distinct)` as a window function would help.  But there is a convenient trick using the sums of `dense_rank()`s.

So, I think this does what you want:

```
select (case when seqnum_asc + seqnum_desc - 1 > 1   -- more than 1 distinct value
             then concat(ordernumber, '-', seqnum_asc)
             else concat(ordernumber, '')            -- just to convert the value to a string
        end) as packagenumber,
        t.*
FROM (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by ordernumber order by warehouse, carrier) as seqnum_asc,
             dense_rank() over (partition by ordernumber order by warehouse desc, carrier desc) as seqnum_desc
      from mytable t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=997ce2fb2fc85303b7dc0ed8d489d873) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  This does not take into account the ordering by the line number -- because your question doesn't mention that at all.  If you only want adjacent rows with the same value to be included in each group, then ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. I haven't heard of dense_rank() before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `Dense_Rank()` instead of `Row_Number()`

**Example**

```
Select [Package-Number] = concat([Order Number]
                                ,left(nullif(count(*) over (partition by [Order Number] ),1),0)
                                 +dense_rank() over (partition by [Order Number],warehouse,carrier  order by Line)*-1 )
       ,Line
       ,Item
       ,Warehouse
       ,Carrier
       ,Quantity 
  From  YourTable
```

**Returns**

[image]